# How to Sum a column of a related table in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask application that tracks shift information, and the orders logged during that shift, the models are set up like this

```py
class Shift(db.Model):
  # Columns
  orders = db.relationship('Orders', lazy='dynamic')


class Orders(db.Model):
  pay = db.Column(db.Integer)
  dash_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('dash.id'))
```

While the user is in the middle of a shift I want to display the total pay they have made so far, and I also will commit it into the Shift table later as well. To get the total pay of all the related orders I tried to query something like

```py
current_shift = Shift.query.filter_by(id=session['shiftID']).first()
orders = current_shift.orders
total_pay = func.sum(orders.pay)
```

But it always returns that `'AppenderBaseQuery' object has no attribute 'pay'`
I know that I can loop through like this

```py
total_pay = 0
for order in orders:
    total_pay += order
```

but that can't be as quick, efficient, or certainly readable as an aggregate function in a query.

My question is this, what is the correct way to sum the Orders.pay columns (or perform aggregate functions of any column) of the related orders?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to go through the shifts table, because you already have all the information that you need in the orders table.

To get the result for a single shift you can do

```py
pay = db_session.query(
          func.sum(Orders.pay)
      ).filter(Orders.shifts_id == shift_id).one()
```

or for multiple shifts

```py
pays = ( 
    db.session.query(Orders.shifts_id, sa.func.sum(Orders.pay))
    .filter(Orders.shifts_id.in_(list_of_shift_ids))
    .group_by(Orders.shifts_id)
    .all()
)
```

Note that both queries return rows as tuples, for example `(50,)`, `[(1, 25,), (2, 50,)]` respectively.